# User defined function in Python won't accept a Series/iterable as `bottom` arguments for a matplotlib bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, function, matplotlib, parameter-passing

Edited:
I am plotting stacked bars from my pandas DataFrame. Code generally works, but when I put the same code in a user defined function and try to plot the bars between 2 specific dates, it returns an error. Here are the codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time_table = pd.DataFrame(data =[['2019-09-03',-1.089987,5.085],
['2019-09-04',-5.982087,-2.7],
['2019-09-05',-2.887029,57.46659545],
['2019-09-06',-5.634726,-47.45]] , columns=['Exec_date','Trade_cost', 'Closed_PnL'])
time_table['Exec_date'] = pd.to_datetime(time_table['Exec_date'] )

def between_dates(df_time , start = pd.to_datetime('09/3/2019'), finish = pd.to_datetime('09/6/2019')):
    mask = (df_time['Exec_date'] >= start ) &(df_time['Exec_date'] <= finish)
    df_time = df_time.loc[mask].copy()
    plot_it(df_time)
    return df_time

def plot_it(time_table):
    fig1=plt.figure()
    axes1 = fig1.add_axes([0.1,0.1,1,1])

    # Plots
    axes1.bar(time_table['Exec_date'], time_table['Closed_PnL'], color='0.7')
    axes1.bar(time_table['Exec_date'], time_table['Trade_cost'],bottom = time_table['Closed_PnL'],color='r')
        plt.show();


between_dates(time_table)
```

the above code works. but if I change the dates in `between_dates` function to anything which doesn't cover all of my data, say change the start to `09/04/2019` it returns this error: `only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`,which, I guess, has probably something to do with functions not being able to send multiple values for `bottom` argument. If I take out the `bottom` or assign a single value to it, my function works without any errors, but the plot is not a stacked bar plot anymore. To Solve the problem, I am using a plotting loop inside my function:

```
def plot_it(time_table):
    fig1=plt.figure()
    axes1 = fig1.add_axes([0.1,0.1,1,1])

    # Plots
    axes1.bar(time_table['Exec_date'], time_table['Closed_PnL'], color='0.7',edgecolor = 'k')
    for i in time_table.index:
        axes1.bar(time_table.loc[i,'Exec_date'], time_table.loc[i,'Trade_cost'],bottom = time_table.loc[i,'Closed_PnL'],
                  color='r')
    plt.show();
```

It works! But doesn't look that great. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of writing this code. Something that doesn't require going through a `for loop` and plotting bars one by one. I read a little about [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), but can't get it to work in this case yet. 
Here is a link to [the code on Github](https://github.com/Meisam-Heidari/Min_code_stackedbar_issue_stack_overflow/blob/master/Plotting%20in%20a%20user%20defined%20function.ipynb) for testing.
So, is there any better way of plotting these stacked bars? Appreciate your help and comments!

Comment: There is no reason the same code should work outside a function, but not inside of it. So you need to come back to the error you get and provide a [mcve] together with the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Included minimal executable code as well as a link to my notebook on GitHub. Also noted that the issue arises when I try to plot between any 2 dates which doesn't cover all the dates in the dataset. If I try to plot the complete date range, it does it without any problems.

Comment: I don't think I understand what the desired outcome is given that some of the data is negative.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, The sum of data can be anything. The error is clear, my code on GitHub shows it. The question is to find a better way for plotting the stacked bar between 2 specific dates, which doesn't include a `for loop` to do the plotting.  I hope it is clear now,

Comment: Oh, you need to use `bottom = df['colname'].values` instead of `bottom = df['colname']`.